# Upload Image Using Path Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I am facing problem in my uploading file using codeigniter.When I create a leave request and upload the image, the image did not appear in the folder path and also did not have a path at the database. Actually, I am doing Leave Request Management  I already insert coding upload in my controller. This is my controller **leaves.php**

***Controller (leaves.php)***

```
   public function upload ()

   {

            $config['upload_path']          = "./upload/";
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            //$config['max_size']             = 100;
            //$config['max_width']            = 1024;
            //$config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('create', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $file_data = $this->upload->data();
                    $data['img'] = base_url().'/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
                    $this->load->view('view', $data);
            }
```

This is my view. Actually I has 2 view that called ***create.php*** and ***view.php***.
***Create.php*** is request leave and also for uploading file and for ***view.php*** is when user want to view their leave request and also the uploading image. This is my code for both view.

***View(create.php)***

```
<? echo form_open_multipart('create/upload');?>
<input type="file" name="image" class=" inputfile" value="<?php echo set_value ('image'); ?>" />
```

***View(view.php)***

```
<label for="image"><?php echo lang ('leaves_view_field_image'); ?>Uploaded File</label>
<img src="?php echo $leave['image']"><?php echo $leave['image']; ?>
```

When I upload the image with the leave request, the image uploading only fetch name file not the whole file in the database. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function upload ()
       {
                $config['upload_path']          = "./upload/";
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                //$config['max_size']             = 100;
                //$config['max_width']            = 1024;
                //$config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('create', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
                        $data['img'] = base_url().'/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
                        $this->load->view('view', $data);
                }
    }
```

**Note:** make sure folder read/write permission give in linux system

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())` change it to `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))` where "`image`" is the same thing as "`$_FILES['image']`" that is the val in your html e.g `<input type="file" name="image">`.
I hope this will help you to upload you file.